# How to completely remove npm config / cache

Tags: node.js, npm

I've just deleted my folders `/usr/lib/node_modules/`, `~/.npm` and `~/.node_modules` to clean my broken `npm` installation.

But `npm` still lists all the packages!

Which file contains the `npm` dependency tree if the folders are all empty?

Comment: you should try deleting node_modules directory from the current dir if it exists